# Quickfix fromApp() method not being called

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am attempting to subscribe to certain message types from one of our providers. I send the `35=BW` message as per their API, and I receive all the `Quote` messages that I need.

However, I can only see them in the quickfix generated log, they are not passing through the `fromApp()` method. Anyone know why that is?

Here are the full messages from the quickfix logs:

```
8=FIXT.1.1|9=101|35=A|34=1|49=ME|52=20190801-21:24:08.974|56=THEM|98=0|108=30|141=Y|1137=9|10=209|
8=FIXT.1.1|9=97|35=A|56=ME|49=THEM|52=20190801-21:24:09|34=1|108=30|141=Y|98=0|1137=9|10=222|
8=FIXT.1.1|9=159|35=BW|34=2|49=ME|52=20190801-21:24:09.165|56=THEM|1346=bc445475-6c3d-49b1-8e69-1fae46fbaa2b|1347=1|1351=1|ApplID=quotes|1357=0|1399=0|10=048|
8=FIXT.1.1|9=129|35=BX|49=THEM|56=ME|34=2|52=20190801-21:24:09|1346=bc445475-6c3d-49b1-8e69-1fae46fbaa2b|1347=1|1348=0|10=058|
8=FIXT.1.1|9=316|35=S|49=THEM|56=ME|34=3|52=20190801-21:24:09|1180=ApplID|1181=0|60=20190730-18:38:13.068519|131=1564181552814-51|117=8SVc72UWLVQ|55=USD/CAD|64=20190731|63=SPOT|453=1|448=AUTO|447=D|452=61|2376=18|132=1.3158|133=1.31586|134=1000000|135=1000000|8021=USD|8022=USD|2533=0|9501=0|2534=0|9502=0|10=061|
8=FIXT.1.1|9=159|35=BW|34=3|49=ME|52=20190801-21:24:14.165|56=THEM|1346=859f354c-6c3f-48dd-880c-435eb5241ab0|1347=4|1351=1|1355=ApplID|1357=0|1399=0|10=163|
```

The messages that I do not receive through my `fromApp()` method are the `Quote` as well as the `35=BX` messages (both application layer basically)

And here are my quickfix settings

```
[DEFAULT]
# Settings which apply to all the Sessions.
ConnectionType=initiator
SenderCompID=ME
ReconnectInterval=30
HeartBtInt=30
FileStorePath=/my/log/path
FileLogPath=/my/log/path
FileLogHeartBeats=Y

[SESSION]
# Settings specifically for one session
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
AppDataDictionary=MyDictionary.xml
TransportDataDictionary=MyTransportDictionary.xml
TargetCompID=THEM
TimeZone=America/New_York
StartTime=06:00:00 US/Central
EndTime=19:00:00 US/Central
Weekdays=Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri
SocketConnectPort=theirPort
SocketConnectHost=their.ip.address
UseDataDictionary=Y
CheckLatency=N
ResetOnLogon=Y
```

Any help greatly appreciated

**EDIT:** I put a breakpoint on the `Session.next()` method, and it's only being called for the `35=A LOGON` message. No application layer messages ever go through it, but they are definitely being saved in the quickfix logs. I tried by sending multiple other subscriptions with the same outcome.

Comment: Which QF are you using: Java or C++?  Don't tag them both.

Comment: What's your fromApp() look like?

Comment: Oh, I thought `quickfix` was a general tag for all framework implementations. I'm using `quickFixJ`.

My `fromApp()` is just a `System.out.println(message)`

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier edited with more info